# how specific a number format in angular2 toString method?

Tags: typescript, angular2-pipe

I want to format my number in angular2 app.
I want always be of 8 numbers.
ex. if I insert:

```
 12345678 -> 12345678
 123 -> 00000123
 123456 -> 00123456
 123456789 ->i'll display a modal error or message(don't care of this)
```

I search but i find only pipes i can't use for this case.
thaks

Answer (score 1):

**pad-start-polyfill.ts**

polyfill from:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

declaration from:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2017.string.d.ts

```
interface String {
  padStart(targetLength: number, padString?: string): string;
}

// https://github.com/uxitten/polyfill/blob/master/string.polyfill.js
// https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

if (!String.prototype.padStart) {
  String.prototype.padStart = function padStart(targetLength, padString) {
    targetLength = targetLength >> 0; //floor if number or convert non-number to 0;
    padString = String(padString || ' ');
    if (this.length > targetLength) {
      return String(this);
    }
    else {
      targetLength = targetLength-this.length;
      if (targetLength > padString.length) {
        padString += padString.repeat(targetLength/padString.length); //append to original to ensure we are longer than needed
      }
      return padString.slice(0, targetLength) + String(this);
    }
  };
}
```

**pad-start.pipe**

```
import 'pad-start-polyfill';
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'padStart'}) export default class {
  transform(value: string, targetLength: number, padString = ' ') {
    return value.padStart(targetLength, padString);
  }
}
```

**temaplate-usage.html**

```
<span>
  {{value | padStart : 8 : '0'}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to complete with zeros

```
function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num + "";
    while (s.length < size)
       s = "0" + s;

    return s;
}
```

In your case, size = 8

Answer (score 0):

a easer way to do it is merge the two response above

**your-pipe.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'minimalLenthNumber'
})
export class MinimalLenthNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(num : number, size: number) : string {
        var s = num + "";
        while (s.length < size)
            s = "0" + s;
        return s;
    }
}
```

at yous modules import, dont miss import this pipe
in my case i have a app.module.ts file that have all modules's my application

**app.module.ts**

```
import { MinimalLenthNumberPipe } from './pipes/minimal-lenth-number.pipe';

@NgModule({
    MinimalLenthNumberPipe
}
```

then import the MinimalLenthNumberPipe where you wanna use it

**some-page.component.ts**

```
<some-tag> {{ 12 | minimalLenthNumber:  4 }} </some-tag>
<!-- the final result will be '0012'-->
```